# Get the decimal point

Tags: c++

How to get decimal point of a number? For example:
If I have 1.5 how to get the 5 number?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. What are the types you want to handle? You have a double, and you would like the decimal representation after the comma into an int? You would like to have 5 stored in an int? Why 5 and not 50?

Comment: @Benoit because I'm only interested in the first digit after dot.

Comment: ... Why would you need the "first digit after the dot", but nothing else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int result = static_cast<int>(fmod(number, 1)*10);
```

EDIT: or simpler and probably faster:

```
int result = static_cast<int>(number*10)%10;
```

EDIT: to make it work also for negative numbers you may do:

```
int result = abs(static_cast<int>(number*10))%10;
```

Comment: you have beaten me on time ;)

Comment: what if we don't know the decimal point position, I mean how to solve this problem in general for any given float number like 12.76, 164.7, 8759.128756, etc. ?

Comment: @Rasoul: The solution works in any situation, it always gives you the first decimal digit.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have `x=234.537`

`floor(x*10)` gives you 2345

you then just need to get the remainder of a division by 10

So:

`int firstDecimal = floor(x*10)%10`

Comment: `int firstDecimal = floor(x*10)%10` will not even compile. `floor` is of floating point type, but `%` requires non-float (int, unsigned, etc.).

Comment: I was not giving a language specific answer. This can be used in pretty much any language. You may need some cast in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
(int) (n*10) % 10
```

Comment: @Nawaz: May or may not. Depends on the platform (hardware).

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice simple way to do it.

```
int GetFirstDecimalPlace( float f )
{
    const float dp = f - floorf( f ); // This simply gives all the values after the 
                                      // decimal point.
    return static_cast< int >( dp * 10.0f ); // This move the value after the decimal 
                                             // point to before it and then casts to an
                                             // int losing all other decimal places.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to work with negative numbers using no macro/function calls:

```
n < 0 ? (int) (-n * 10) % 10 : (int) (n * 10) % 10
```

Comment: Too complicated. Could be `static_cast<int>((n>=0?n:-n)*10)%10`. But I don't see any reason, why not to call abs().

Comment: You're right, this way it's simpler. And there is no reason not to all abs() except maybe for performance reasons, but that's negligible. I just wanted to show a way to do that using tools provided by the language, not the library. Any reason to use static_cast<int> instead of just (int), by the way?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason for using static_int instead of just (int) is to mark places in program where explicit casts are performed. It is done for readability reasons.