# separating decimal points into two integers

Tags: c++

I have been given `double x = 23.456;` and two integer d and c.
I have to break it so that d gets the value 23 and c gets the value 456.
I thought of the following:-

```
int d;
d=(int)x;
```

but I cannot think of what to do with c as it is an integer and  if i write

```
c=(x-d)*1000;
```

then it might be applicable for this case only and not for any other case.

Is there any way to get the number of digits after the decimal and then multiply it with equal number of zeros.
Please help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427897/get-the-decimal-point)

Comment: How many significant digits do you care about?  What if the fractional portion contains 15 digits?  Are you going to store that entire 15-digit value?  Which leads to the next question -- what is the high-level problem you're trying to solve that needs the number to be broken up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could repeatedly multiply it by 10, until there is nothing after decimal point.

```
double c = x - d;

while(c - floor(c) > 0.0)
{c *= 10;}
```

you may also need to `#include <math.h>` for floor function, which rounds down a number. e.g. `floor(4.9)` returns 4.0

Comment: Since floating point is approximate, this may result in a very large `c`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197139/how-to-find-digits-after-decimal#comment69594156_41197139 for a related question.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point calculations are little bit tricky in C++ (same is true for Java and other languages). You should avoid their direct comparison and do some other stuff to get predictable result when using them, consider:

```
double d1=1.1;
double d2= d1 / 10.0;

if(d2==0.11)cout << "equals" << endl;
else cout << "not equals" << endl;   //result is "not equals"

d1=1.99;
float  f1=0.01f;
double d3=d1+f1;
if(d3==2.0)cout << "equals" << endl;
else cout << "not equals" << endl;  //result is "not equals"

d1=1.99;
d2=0.01;
d3=d1+d2-2.0;
if(d3==0.0)cout << "equals" << endl;
else cout << "not equals" << endl;   //result is "not equals"
```

As for practical solution of the problem I can suggest 2 variants:
Var 1 is to use a function that allows to specify number of digits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


void split_double(const double value, int& i_part, int& r_part,
                  const int max_digits_after_dp, int min_digits_after_dp){


    auto powerOfTenL = [](int power){ int result = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<power;++i)result *= 10;
        return result;
    };
    //Get integral part
    i_part = (int)value;
    double temp = (value-i_part);
    double pOfTen = powerOfTenL(max_digits_after_dp);
    temp *= pOfTen;
    //Get real part
    r_part = round(temp);

    //Remove zeroes at the right in real part
    int num_of_d = max_digits_after_dp;
    if(min_digits_after_dp>max_digits_after_dp)
        min_digits_after_dp=max_digits_after_dp;
    while (num_of_d>min_digits_after_dp) {
        //If the number is divisible by 10, divide it by 10
        if(0==(r_part%10)) { r_part /=10; num_of_d--;
        }
        else break; //Last digit is not 0
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double value = 10.120019;
    int ipart,rpart;
    const int digitsMax = 6;
    const int digitsMin = 3;

    split_double(value,ipart,rpart,digitsMax,digitsMin);
    cout<<"Double " <<value << " has integral part " <<ipart
       <<" and real part "<<rpart<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Second variant to solve the problem is to use C/C++ formatting functions like vsprintf and then split the resulting string.