# How to find digits after decimal?

Tags: c++, decimal

I want to write a program in C++ to cin a Decimal number and cout the digits after Decimal
for example 0.26547 -> 5.

I wrote this but not work correctly:

```
       int main()
 {
 int i=0,b;
float a ;
  cin>>a ;
   while(a!=0)
  {
    a*=10 ;
    b=a ;
    a-=b ;
    i+=1 ;
 }
 cout<<i ;
 }
```

For example for 0.258 instead of 3, returns 20.
can one explain me what is the problem of this code ?
thank you

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: [Is this the same homework problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197021/separating-decimal-points-into-two-integers)?

Comment: The problem is that floating point numbers are approximate. `.258` can't be represented exactly, internally it's something like `.25800000000000001` or `.25799999999999999`.

Comment: this whole idea is a bit off. `float`s have no notion of decimal digits whatsoever, and there is no uniform way to introduce one

Comment: mr barmar  you alright i found . how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 2):

C++ permits decimal representation of floating point numbers, but as far as I know all extant implementations use binary representation. And then the idea of storing the user's decimal number specification as a floating point value, loses critical information about the decimal digits: they're simply not there any more. So to count the decimal digits in the specification, you have to store it as a string.

Pseudo-code:

1. input number specification as a string, e.g. using `getline`.
2. verify that it's a valid number specification, e.g. using `stod`.
3. scan for the first period from the right, call this position P.
4. scan for the maximum number of decimal digits from position P.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why your code does not work (What compiler are you using?), but I think it might related to

```
b=a;
```

Try explicitly casting your float to an int

```
b = int(a);
```

Alternatively, you could choose not to use an int, and round a float down using the function `floor` by including math.h `#include <math.h>`

```
float a = 5.9f;
float b = floor(a);
a -= b;
```